# Calculating pmf and cdf for 20 sided dice in R

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to create two functions that would calculate the probability mass function (pmf) and cumulative distribution function (cdf) for a dice of 20 sides.

In the function I would use one argument, y for the side(from number 1 to 20). I should be able to put a vector and it would return the value for each of the variable.

If the value entered is non-discrete, it should then return zero in the result and a warning message.

This is what have solved so far for PMF:

```
PMF= function(side) {

  a = NULL   

  for (i in side)
  {
    a= dbinom(1, size=1, prob=1/20)
    print(a)
  }

}
```

And this is what I got for CDF:

```
CDF= function(side) {
  a = NULL   
  for (i in side)
  {
    a= pnorm(side)
    print(a)
  }

}
```

I am currently stuck with the warning message and the zero in result. How can I assing in the function the command line for that?

Next,how can I plot these two functions on the same plot on a specific interval (for example 1,12)?

Did I use the right function for calculating cdf and pmf?

Comment: Note that `dbinom(1, size = 1, prob = 1/20)` is always `1/20`, so calculating it every time is unnecessary.

Comment: I know that, but if I think I should use that whole formula because I want to calculate it for every i. If not, is there a shorter way to do it? ( and I wanted to show that I calculated with the pmf formula in r)

Comment: For every `i`, it is 1/20. Thus `1/20` is a shorter way. Or `0.05` for no calculation at all. Working on an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose the following simplifications:

```
PMF <- function(side) {
   x <- rep(0.05, length(side))
   bad_sides <- ! side %in% 1:20 # sides that aren't in 1:20 are bad
   x[bad_sides] <- 0             # set bad sides to 0
   # warnings use the warning() function. See ?warning for details
   if (any(bad_sides)) warning("Sides not integers between 1 and 20 have 0 probability!")
   # print results is probably not what you want, we'll return them instead.
   return(x)
}
```

For the CDF, I assume you mean the probability of rolling a number less than or equal to the side given, which is `side / 20`. (`pnorm` is the wrong function... it gives the CDF of the normal distribution.)

```
CDF <- function(side) {
    return(pmin(1, pmax(0, floor(side) / 20)))
}
```

Technically, the CDF is defined for non-integer values. The `CDF` of 1.2 is just the same as the CDF of 1, so I use `floor` here. If you want to make it more robust, you could make it `min(1, floor(side) / 20)` to make sure it doesn't exceed 1, and similarly a `max()` with 0 to make sure it's not negative. Or you could just try not to give it negative values or values over 20.

Plotting:

```
my_interval <- 1:12
plot(range(my_interval), c(0, 1), type = "n")
points(my_interval, PMF(my_interval))
lines(my_interval, CDF(my_interval), type = "s")
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! You are really helpful.

But I have a question, because I am a beginner:

Can you explain what `bad_sides <- ! side %in% 1:20 ` does? What does %in% mean?

Comment: See `?"%in%"`, run `c(1, 2, 3.5, 10, 100) %in% 1:20`. Then run `! c(1, 2, 3.5, 10, 100) %in% 1:20`, and if you need to, read `?"!"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I might have more question later... But, thanks again!

Comment: Can you add an interval for the cdf if the number is below or outisde 20? That should be the range for a 20 sided dice.

Comment: @Trik23 not quite sure what you mean by "add an interval", but I modified the `CDF` function to make it correct for the whole number line.

Comment: As in the pmf I would like to have similar function, where for 0 and above values it would give a warning. Can you write the second function the same as the first?

Comment: I think you can figure it out from here. You just need something like `if (any(side > 20))`...